# Combining an element in a tuple to another tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
player_stat =[
    ('Harry Kane', '34', '19'),
    ('Player E', '35', '20'),
    ('Lionel Messi', '34', '14'),
    ('Player F', '35', '11'),
    ('Player A', '35', '17'),
    ('Player B', '35', '15'),
    ('Kylian Mbappe', '35', '18'),
    ('Player C', '35', '18'),
    ('Erling Haaland','35','21'),
    ('Player D', '35', '19'),
]

market_value = [
    ('Erling Haaland','138M'),
    ('Harry Kane', '120M'),
    ('Lionel Messi', '118.7M'),
    ('Kylian Mbappe', '115M'),
    ('Player A', '107M'),
    ('Player B', '108M'),
    ('Player E', '100M'),
    ('Player F', '98M'),
]
```

I want to for loop through these tuples and basically if the name is equal I want to add the market value to the player stats. (Player C,D have no data)

I tried:

```
for i in range(len(player_stat)):
    for j in range(len(market_value)):
        if(player_stat[i][0]==market_value[j][0]):
            player_stat[i] = player_stat[i] + (str(market_value[j][1]),)
            break
        else:
            player_stat[i] = player_stat[i] + ('undef',)
```

Hoping to have End result being:

```
player_stat =[
    ('Harry Kane', '34', '19', '120M'),
    ('Player E', '35', '20', '100M'),
    ('Lionel Messi', '34', '14', '118.7M'),
    ('Player F', '35', '11', '98M'),
    ('Player A', '35', '17', '107M'),
    ('Player B', '35', '15', '108M'),
    ('Kylian Mbappe', '35', '18', '115M'),
    ('Player C', '35', '18', 'unknown'),
    ('Erling Haaland','35','21', '138M'),
    ('Player D', '35', '19', 'unknown),
]
```

Comment: Hi, you're having problems because you use wrong data structures. Both vars need to be dicts, not lists of tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using *market_value* as lookup dictionary:

```
market_dict = dict(market_value)
player_stat = [p + (market_dict.get(p[0],'unknown'),) for p in player_stat]
print(player_stat)
```

---

```
[('Harry Kane', '34', '19', '120M'),
 ('Player E', '35', '20', '100M'),
 ('Lionel Messi', '34', '14', '118.7M'),
 ('Player F', '35', '11', '98M'),
 ('Player A', '35', '17', '107M'),
 ('Player B', '35', '15', '108M'),
 ('Kylian Mbappe', '35', '18', '115M'),
 ('Player C', '35', '18', 'unknown'),
 ('Erling Haaland', '35', '21', '138M'),
 ('Player D', '35', '19', 'unknown')]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve your desired result by converting these tupled list into dictionary and append the player_stat dictionary by iterating over market_value dictionary.

Note: Since you can't add data into tuple, so convert it into a list.

```
### first create a dict
player_stat={i[0]:list(i[1:]) for i in player_stat}
market_value={key: value for key, value in market_value}

#### append the player_stat dict by iterating over market_value

for k,v in market_value.items():
    if k in player_stat:
        player_stat[k].append(v)
for k,v in player_stat.items():
    if k not in market_value:
        player_stat[k].append('unknown')

print(player_stat) #### a dictionary
```

Now you can convert player_stat dictionary into list again

```
player_stat=list(player_stat.items())
```

now you can get the desired results

```
print(player_stat)

[('Harry Kane', ['34', '19', '120M']), 
('Player E', ['35', '20', '100M']), 
('Lionel Messi', ['34', '14', '118.7M']), 
('Player F', ['35', '11', '98M']), 
('Player A', ['35', '17', '107M']), 
('Player B', ['35', '15', '108M']), 
('Kylian Mbappe', ['35', '18', '115M']), 
('Player C', ['35', '18','unknown']), 
('Erling Haaland', ['35', '21', '138M']), 
('Player D', ['35', '19','unknown'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn second collection into dictionary and use it to fill the results:

```py
mv_dict = dict(market_value)
result = [(x, y, z, mv_dict.get(x, "unknown")) for x, y, z in player_stat]
```

If you are willing to use external libraries (`pandas`) you can easily join data with:

```py
players = pd.DataFrame(player_stat, columns=['name', 'games', 'goals'])
mv = pd.DataFrame(market_value, columns=['name', 'value'])
players.merge(mv, how='left').fillna("unknown")
```

Answer (score 0):

At least `market_value` should be converted to a dictionary.

```
player_stat =[
    ('Harry Kane', '34', '19'),
    ('Player E', '35', '20'),
    ('Lionel Messi', '34', '14'),
    ('Player F', '35', '11'),
    ('Player A', '35', '17'),
    ('Player B', '35', '15'),
    ('Kylian Mbappe', '35', '18'),
    ('Player C', '35', '18'),
    ('Erling Haaland','35','21'),
    ('Player D', '35', '19'),
]

market_value = [
    ('Erling Haaland','138M'),
    ('Harry Kane', '120M'),
    ('Lionel Messi', '118.7M'),
    ('Kylian Mbappe', '115M'),
    ('Player A', '107M'),
    ('Player B', '108M'),
    ('Player E', '100M'),
    ('Player F', '98M'),
]

market_value = dict(market_value)
print(market_value)
```

This will give you

```
{'Erling Haaland': '138M',
 'Harry Kane': '120M',
 'Kylian Mbappe': '115M',
 'Lionel Messi': '118.7M',
 'Player A': '107M',
 'Player B': '108M',
 'Player E': '100M',
 'Player F': '98M'}
```

Now it's a simple list comprehension with a lookup.

```
players = [player + (market_value.get(player[0], 'unknown'),) for player in player_stat]
```

The result is

```
[('Harry Kane', '34', '19', '120M'),
 ('Player E', '35', '20', '100M'),
 [...]
 ('Erling Haaland', '35', '21', '138M'),
 ('Player D', '35', '19', 'unknown')]
```

Answer (score 0):

using this OneLiner can help you, but the names of the player is not in the first cell.

```
print([tuple(set(player+market)) for player in player_stat for market in market_value if player[0]==market[0]])
```

also, I suggest you use `Iteration` instead of the `Tuple` of other types, because of the Low memory usage and you can set `Unkown` values when you give it for print or etc.